# Tela preta no emulador android

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native, emulador

Eu estou tentando iniciar o emulador pelo android studio e genymotion mas nos dois fica uma tela preta no emulador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ser minha placa gráfica que é péssima, mas teria alguma forma de consertar isso? Ou algum outro emulador decente para desenvolvimento android?
Também tentei testar meus apps em um dispositivo físico, primeiro testei com o celular do meu uso e deu certo, depois tentei com um celular que comprei para isso (j5 metal) mas fica dando erro

```
C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Desktop\Junior\Android\curso-react-native\exercicios>react-n
tive run-android --deviceId 8031fe9d
Starting JS server...
Building the app...

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Desktop\Junior\Android\cur
o-react-native\exercicios\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\inde
.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Desktop\Juni
r\Android\curso-react-native\exercicios\android\app\build\intermediates\blame\r
s\release.
> Unable to delete directory C:\Users\MIDIASILK\Desktop\Junior\Android\curso-re
ct-native\exercicios\android\app\build\intermediates\blame\res\release.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 27s
35 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 19 up-to-date
Could not build the app, read the error above for details.

Running C:\Users\MIDIASILK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 8031
e9d reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Installing the app on the device (cd android && adb -s 8031fe9d install app/bui
d/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
adb: failed to stat app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk: No such file or direct
ry
Command failed: C:\Users\MIDIASILK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb
-s 8031fe9d install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

Starting the app on 8031fe9d (C:\Users\MIDIASILK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/plat
orm-tools/adb -s 8031fe9d shell am start -n com.exercicios/com.exercicios.MainA
tivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.exercicios/.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaun
hParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.exercicios/com.exercicios.MainActivity} does not exi
t.
```

Rodei o mesmo comando no meu celular e funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tive o mesmo problema. Eu acho que o problema é que o Android Studio gera esse `app-debug.apk`. Por algum motivo nesse esse diretório

`android/app/build/output/apk`

Mas esse diretório, possui diretórios filhos, `debuge` e `release`. É por isso que o **react-native-cli** da esse erro, pois não consegue encontrar o `app-debug.apk` que está no diretório `debug`.

**Eu resolvi mudando o `app-debug.apk` para**

`android/app/build/output/apk`

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi desinstalando o Device Emulator e criando novamente.

Utilizei as mesmas configurações anteriores como Device e AVD.

Não descobri o porque desse erro mas tenho a sensação de ser algo relacionado ao meu processador AMD.